# What is the best method for scaling/resizing a wndows bitmap?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opencv, bitmap

I'm working on a C++ application that does some image analysis.
Client applications provide us bitmaps (either HBITMP or LPBITMAP).
Some of the images will need to be scaled/resized.

Our library does not have a visual component, so it does not have access to an HDC. Likewise, our API does not require one from the calling clients.

What is the best way to scale a bitmap image?
What is the cleanest (straight forward) and best performing implementation.

I do have access to the opencv libraries as part of this project.

Thanks,
 JohnB

Comment: I think this question might get knocked back John, because you are asking for people's opinion.

Comment: StretchBlt would be an easy solution.

Comment: GDI+.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @JonathanPotter that would still require a DC, though arguably bitmap scaling to pixel coordinates would be a device-independent thing... would it? (that is, would the results be different with a different DPI? because if not we could just use two screen DCs...) Of course, that assumes you can get a DIB out of a DC's default bitmap, anyway... (I have not tried, so I don't know)

Comment: @selbie how fast would GDI+ even be, especially paired with OpenCV (which by nature has to be high-performance)?

Comment: @JohnB you will also need to know the scaling mode. Do you want "nearest neighbor" (the blocky just-duplicate-the-pixels kind) or some sort of filtering scale? If you do use `StretchBlt()` that names its stretch modes differently as well...

Comment: @JohnB: `CreateCompatibleDC(0)` gets you a DC easily enough. Just because you don't have a window doesn't mean you can't have a DC to play with.

Comment: I recommended GDI+ because I've used it several times in shipping code for some general resizing of bitmaps and images. It provides a nice abstraction on top of GDI, takes care of that 'i don't have an HDC' issue that you mention, and provides a few scaling algorithms and codecs (jpg,png) not found in GDI.  Also supports saving to file. That's why I recommended it. But it's scalars and jpeg quantization might be out of date with the latest technology. It really depends on how much image quality you want to achieve, your app's perf requirements, and how much you need to learn.